# How do I use R to manipulate this data set?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two datasets as follow:

Dataset 1:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 6 |
| a | 77 |
| a | 88 |
| b | 99 |
| b | 00 |

Dataset 2:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | X |
| a | 2 | X |
| a | 3 | Y |
| b | 4 | Y |
| b | 5 | Z |
| b | 6 | Z |

I am looking to generate:

| Col1 | NewCol2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | X |
| a | Y |
| b | Y |
| b | Z |
| a | 77 |
| a | 88 |
| b | 99 |
| b | 00 |

I really appreciate any input. This will save a lot of time in the future.

Thank you!

I do this on excel but I am trying to automate it.

Comment: This is a merge/join operation, cleaned up with a coalescing (ifelse/is.na) transformation. Base R: `merge(Dataset1, Dataset2, by = c("Col1", "Col2"), all.x = TRUE) |> transform(NewCol2 = ifelse(is.na(Col3), Col2, Col3)) |> subset(select = -c(Col2, Col3)) |> unique()`. Dplyr: `left_join(Dataset1, Dataset2, by = c("Col1", "Col2")) %>% mutate(NewCol2 = coalesce(Col3, Col2)) %>% select(-Col2, -Col3) %>% unique()`

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please explain the logic of this code in simple english?

Comment: I can only scratch the surface; the dupe-links do a much better job about explaining and visually displaying what is happening in a merge/join operation. It's certainly a "core" operation in data-management in that once you get it, it is useful in countless ways for normalizing, cleaning, and combining data. It's not something Excel does in a spreadsheet (its PowerQuery can do it), so it is often a new trick to learn.